# Opening many files in Eclipse with a script for formatting

Tags: eclipse, file, formatting

So i want to format a bunch of files that i have to a certain standard. The problem is, there is A LOT of files. Is there anyway to have Eclipse open a file, hit CTRL+SHIFT+F (to format the file), save it, close it, then open the next file and repeat that process through a directory that i specify?

I don't have any experience with scripting so i have not even attempted doing something like this. I looked into plugins for Eclipse that could maybe do this but i really didn't get anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on any source folder in the Package Explorer (including the root of the project) and select Source > Format, or Source > Cleanup (which gives you even more control than a simple format)

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on a folder in the Navigator or Package Explorer view and select Source -> Format.  This will format all the files in the selected directory.